# Match values accross tabs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have the following scenario:

I have a 1 tab with ~600 Event IDs and Event Names. Then I have another tab with ~50 Event IDs and Event Names. What I want to do is to see if the 50 events in the second tab appear in tab 1. If they do, I want to know if the event names match. Essentially, I want to return a match yes no regardless of the ID order.

My problem with Excel is that apparently the values needs to be in the proper order for me to match them and clearly I can't do that in tab 1 since I have way more values. Could someone help?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you post the formula you have tried?

Comment: =MATCH and =INDEX will be your friends here. Please lookup how to use these guys

Answer (score 0):

try a formula along these lines in Sheet2, with the 50 events. I assume that the 600 event IDs are in Sheet1, with the ID in column A and the Event Name in column B on each sheet. Change the formula according to your sheet names and columns.

```
=if(isnumber(match(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)),if(index(Sheet1!B:B,match(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))=B2,"Yes, description matches","No, description does not match"),"Event code not found")
```

The sort order of the data does not matter if you use the third parameter of Match() set to 0 or False.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this pretty easily using =countifs([range to search],[criteria to match],[range to search],[criteria to match]) which returns 1 if there is a match and 0 if there is not. **Don't forget the S**, =countif won't work unless you're only matching ID or matching Name.

Specify the range to search in your full events table for each of your two criteria followed by the single value in your specific events table you need to match.

Your full event table is Table1 and your specific events are housed in Table2. Notice your full events table includes events matching an ID and a Name, but not both, of your single unmatched specific event #448 "Theirs".

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Event_ID],[@[Event_ID]],Table1[Event_Name],[@[Event_Name]])
```

[image: Event_full_specific]